# Python set global variable in namespace of only partially imported module

Tags: python, global-variables, python-import

I would like to import a function from a python subscript (test_sub.py) into a main python script (test_main.py). As the function uses global variables (this is intended), the variables in test_main.py need to be bound to the namespace of test_sub.py to be known there. Is there a way to avoid a duplicate test_sub import? And equally importantly to avoid that other, unused functions are imported as well (since else a single `import test_sub` could be used)?

**test_sub.py:**

```
def test_func_a():
    print(a)

def test_func_b():
    print(b)

def test_func_c():
    print(c)
```

**test_main.py:**

```
from test_sub import test_func_a

a = 'Hello, a'

import test_sub
test_sub.a = a

test_func_a()
```

Comment: I knew there must be some reason people avoid global variables...

Comment: *"unused functions are imported as well"* — [Jein](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=jein)!? The entire `test_sub` module will be evaluated anyway, all the functions within it will be defined and exist in memory, whether you `import` them or not. `from .. import ..` makes a name directly available in your scope, and yes, in that sense "doesn't import" other functions. But if you just `import test_sub` and simply *don't access the functions you don't want to use*, then there's really no practical difference to "not importing them".

Comment: @deceze, I wonder, what would be the actual real world answer to a problem like this.  I am just learning programming, but wouldn't it generally be not to use global variables in the first place and put them in a class or an object?

Comment: @Martynas Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can write as followed
**test_main.py**

```
import test_sub
a = 'Hello, a'
test_sub.a = a
test_sub.test_func_a()
```